# Define renderer class dynamically in Django view function

Tags: python, django, django-views, renderer

How can I define the renderer class inside the Djanog old api_view function depending on some condition? To have something like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def can_render_2_things(request):
    if some_comdition:
       renderer_classes = [PDFRenderer]
    else:
       renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the attributes `accepted_renderer` and `accepted_media_type` on the `request` yourself if the `renderer_classes` list you want to set contains **only one** renderer class. This will cause the correct renderer to be used:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def can_render_2_things(request):
    if some_comdition:
       renderer = PDFRenderer()
    else:
       renderer = JSONRenderer()
    request.accepted_renderer = renderer
    request.accepted_media_type = renderer.media_type
```

But this is not very useful if you want to set more renders, I would advice you to simply move to using class based views instead of function based ones and use the `APIView`:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class CanRender2Things(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if some_comdition:
            self.renderer_classes = [PDFRenderer]
        else:
            self.renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
```

Comment: Think the renderer needs to be an instance `request.accepted_renderer = PDFRenderer()`

Comment: @MohamedFeddad yes it does, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) you can use different responses objects:

```
from django.http import FileResponse, JsonResponse
@api_view(['GET'])
def can_render_2_things(request):
    if some_comdition:
       response = FileResponse(open('myfile.png', 'rb'))
    else:
       response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'}, encoder=myJsonEncoder)
```